# PHP/MySQL - DELETE FROM not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

I decided to add a delete feature to my program, and for some reason, the DELETE FROM is not working.  I have provided some useful code that would be helpful:

JavaScript:

```
function removeAgeGender(id) {
     console.log("Entering removeAgeGender");
     if (id == 'national age gender') {
         var data = $('[name="remove_age_gender[]"]').serialize();
         console.log(data);
         $.ajaxSetup({async:false});
         $.post('/CensusDatabase/database_scripts/NationalAgeGender.php', {remove_age_gender : data });
         nationalAgeGender();
     }
     if (id == 'arizona age gender') {
         var data = $('[name="remove_age_gender[]"]').serialize();
         $.ajaxSetup({async:false});
         $.post('/CensusDatabase/database_scripts/ArizonaAgeGender.php',  {remove_age_gender : data });
         arizonaAgeGender();
     }
}
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['remove_age_gender'])) {
    $boxData = $_POST['remove_age_gender'];
    $removeValue = array();
    parse_str($boxData, $removeValue);
    removeRow($removeValue, $link);
}

function removeRow($removeValue, $link) {
    $removeValue = $removeValue['remove_age_gender'];
    $value = $removeValue[0];
    $query = "DELETE FROM national_age_gender_demographics WHERE age_group='$value'";
    $escapedQuery = mysqli_real_escape_string($query);
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$escapedQuery);
    if(!$result)  die( "Query: " . $escapedQuery . "\nError:" . mysql_error() );
}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You've vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), for one. You have no error handling in your code, and are simply assuming success. And you are doing your escape call incorrectly. You do **NOT** escape the entire query. that simply introduces syntax errors. You escape individual bits of data you're inserting INTO the query string.

Comment: This is simply for a class assignment, and a delete function is required.

Comment: No, `$value` is the first element of the array.  Since `$value` needs to be surrounded by single quotes, how do I properly escape it?

Comment: Have you verified `$value` is indeed a correct value, and that there are rows in your database where `age_group` is exactly equal to that value?

Comment: don't use `mysqli_real_escape_string` on whole query string. Use it on the different values (`$value` in your case).

Comment: I think @MarcB is correct.  The fact you're escaping an entire SQL string screws up the syntax.  Escape `$value`, not `$query`

Comment: `$value` comes from input from a text box, and I have a database entry where the `age_group` value is "Pink".  I tried entering it, however, it doesn't seem to work.

EDIT: Just tried escaping $value, still failing.

Comment: Please do us a favour and give us the content of all interesting variables in your code. E.g. `$_POST`, `$removeValue`, `$link` and `$query` at least.

Comment: How do I get the content of these variables and display them?

Comment: `var_dump($var)` - and then update your question with the values.

Comment: I tried using var_dump(), and can't get the values to display.  Where do I display them?

Comment: You should probably see them in Firebug in the network tab, where the Ajax calls are listed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `mysqli_real_escape_string` on the *query*, but on query parameters (i.e. `$value`).  Your `'` that are part of the string literal syntax for the column value are being escaped incorrectly leading to invalid syntax.

Better yet, you should use prepare, bind param, and execute:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM national_age_gender_demographics WHERE age_group = ?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $value);
mysqli_execute($stmt);
```

Comment: Oh, this worked.  Thanks.  Perhaps my old version was being blocked by WAMP.

Answer (score 1):

As I said above. You do NOT escape the entire query. That'll simply produce syntax errors. This is the proper (but still wrong) sequence:

```
$value = $removeValue[0];
$escaped = mysqli_real_escape_string($value);

$query = "DELETE FROM national_age_gender_demographics WHERE age_group='$escaped'";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
```

Consider what happens when you escape the entire query: All SQL metacharacterrs become escaped, so you're actually making the query be:

```
DELETE FROM .... WHERE age_group=\'...\'
```

Escaping the quotes make them no longer be quotes - they just become plain text, and now you're trying to matcn your `age_group` field against a field whose name is `'somevalue'`.

To make this entirely proper, you should not be escaping data yourself. You use a prepared statement, and/or SQL placeholders, e.g.

```
$stmt = mysql_prepare('DELETE FROM ... WHERE age_group=?');
$stmt->exec(array($value));
```

This is non-functional code, but should give you the basic idea. Unless you know EXACTLY what you're doing, you never EVER let raw data into an SQL query, unless it's via placeholders.